# How to handle layer specific Dependency Injection in a reusable dll with ninject?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

We use ninject as our DI solution. How do I create a self sustaining class library dll with its own internal IOC. Basically I have created a service that does something and I want to register the bindings in the dll and just hand it to other people. I don't want them to care about any binding in my dll.

In the dll:

```
public class FirstService : IFirstService 
{
    public FirstService(ISecondService secondService, IThirdService thirdService)
    {
        //Saves locally
    }
    //Does stuff with second and third services
}
```

What the end user does:

```
public class ThirdService : IThirdService 
{
    //Create the actual implementation of this
}
```

What I want inside the dll:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
    {
        kernel.Bind<IFirstService>.To<FirstService>();
        kernel.Bind<ISecondService>.To<SecondService>();
    }
```

I don't think I want to use IKernel here though, due to possible memory leakage.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "internal IOC". IOC stands for "inversion of control", so if you're designing services, you are giving control over to the host application to do the dependency injection. if you are injecting things into your services internally, you're probably doing it wrong. can you expand your question with concrete examples/questions?

Comment: @davethieben Updated with what I am trying to accomplish

Comment: I think the general approach is to let people bind how they want to, then you just release another nuget like `MyService.Unity` or `MyService.Ninject` which then have that bootstrapper in which has all these files hooked up for them. The same approach that `WebApi` has, so there is `Unity.WebApi` and `Ninject.WebApi`. But yours would be the other way round and you would import each IoC container and configure it specially for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 4 basic design approaches to DLLs that are commonly in use:

1. An application layer.
2. A plug-in.
3. A library.
4. A framework.

It sounds like you have one of the last 2, but it is not possible to tell based on your question which prototype you are referring to.

For an application layer, you would typically compose the components inside of the application, in the [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/), as close to the point of entry of the **main executable** application as possible.

For a plugin, it would typically have its own internal composition root that is fired by some method or event of the application it is plugging into (based on that application's composition root). This is sometimes facilitated by *modules* in DI containers.

A library would typically not have any internal composition, but would provide an API (sometimes implemented as a fluent [builder](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/builder)) that makes it easy for the client application to compose the pieces together. See [this post](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-library/) for a couple of ideas about how to do that.

A framework would need to have 1 or more explicit extension points for the application to integrate into. Think of how MVC controllers work. There is an internal scanning implementation that by default can instantiate any object that implements a certain interface. There is also an [abstract factory](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/abstract_factory) that can be used to inject dependencies if the default constructor is not available (in MVC, that is [IControllerFactory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.icontrollerfactory%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)). See [this post](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/05/19/di-friendly-framework/) for more information about how to make a DI friendly framework.